# Visual Studio 2013 with Angular2 and Typescript

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, typescript, angular

I'm using [the angular2 QUICKSTART](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) and I have a problem where Visual Studio don't recognize **Angular2** with **typescript** import Modules, in rest all it's fine:

[image]

It says:

> Cannot find module 'angular2/platform/browser'

My app :

- is compiling .ts files without errors
- it runs in browser without errors
- if I open the project in VS code it works fine, no errors in IDE

I know that typescript should read .d.ts file directly from **node_modules** --> **angular2**, but anyway I tried to add angular2 **DefinitelyTyped** and still not worked.

Atm I use VS 2013 update 5 with typescript 1.5 installed (I also tried with 1.75)

Comment: hah, indeed, maybe I should try the 2015 version :)

Comment: I'd also not bother with DefinitelyTyped any more, the typings there haven't been updated in months and wont any more, everything is provided by the npm package now

Comment: Yeah. The angular2 definitions in DefinitelyTyped should probably be deleted

Comment: And your TS version is really old, and some of their typings use features from TS 1.7.x. You downgrade it, upgrade it again :D

Comment: Install the latest version of Visual Studio 2015.  Then go to typescriptlang.org and download and install the latest typescript extension for VS.  I highly recommend creating your a new project in ASP.NET 5 (it is a perfect environment to work with angular imo).  Follow the instructions at angular.io to set up your project.  You will be ready to rock and roll.

Comment: I installed Visual Studio 2015 and it works. Seems like it's an issue only with VS 2013.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Solved by using Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: was it fixed with VS 2013? VS 2015 is another version where it works. Answer does not go well with the question. question remains the same - how to setup ng2 dev environment on VS 2013. Hope some has the answer

Answer (score 0):

Please right click on the visual studio project and click on the Properties        option, Then select Typescript Build,default 'none' is selected, change it to 'CommonJs'.

If again any problem regarding 'experimentalDecorators' persists unload the project and add `<TypeScriptExperimentalDecorators>true</TypeScriptExperimentalDecorators>`statement inside the `PropertyGroup` tag.

Again problem exists on building the project such as 'could not find the name Map', 'could not find the name Promise', or 'could not find the name Set' try to change the target to 'es6' in the tsconfig.json