# SystemJS modules with Visual Studio 2013 and TypeScript

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, typescript, ecmascript-6, systemjs

I'm trying to use SystemJS modules in Visual Studio 2013 with TypeScript, but Visual Studio shows errors.

This is my **setup**:

- Installed TypeScript Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 1.8.5.0
- Uninstalled lower versions of TypeScript
- Project file (VS 2013 does not support tsconfig.json):

  `<TypeScriptToolsVersion>1.8</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
  <TypeScriptModuleKind >system</TypeScriptModuleKind>
  <TypeScriptTarget>es5</TypeScriptTarget>`

This is what I **see**:

- My project compiles successfully
- In the browser, AngularJs runs successfully
- But in Visual Studio, I see squiggly lines. Upon hovering it says 'expression statement is not assignment or call':

[image]

This issue is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34406087/visual-studio-2013-with-angular2-and-typescript), however, the answer there is 'use VS 2015', which simply is not an option for me.

Is there any way to use SystemJS with TypeScript in Visual Studio 2013? It doesn't have to be ES6-style modules, just any combination of SystemJS and TypeScript will do. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that there just isn't a solution for this. Upgrading to VS2015 is the only way to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you already tried to set SystemJS as module system in the preferences:
[image: pref vb]

If still doesn't work, try to follow this guide: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1060262/First-Angular-App-with-TypeScript-and-Visual-Studi
from "Setting Up Visual Studio Project".

By the way, VB 2013 is a very old version of the software, is there any reason why shouldn't you migrate to a newer version?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. I think the configuration UI is the same thing as setting the options directly in the project file, which I did (<TypeScriptModuleKind >system</TypeScriptModuleKind>). I followed the guide but to no avail, squiggly lines are still shown. I guess updating to VS2015 will be necessary...

Comment: I really think so, even if you google a little bit you won't find anything related to vb2013 and SystemJS. Today for example I had to manually install ActionScript compiler to be used with IntelliJ idea, the default compiler 4 versions older didn't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

You may need `--allowSyntheticDefaultImports` if angular doesn't have a default export.